# "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead" When using Node.js 18.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

When I use the `aws-sdk` module Node.js 18.x:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('Hello!');
    // some code
};
```

I got this error:

```
{
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
    "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
    "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)",
    "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
    "    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)",
    "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:921:16)",
    "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:970:86)",
    "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:16)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
  ]
}
```

The same code works fine with late versions for example `Node.js 16.x`.

What is the reason of this error, and how can we avoid it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Node18 for Lambda uses JavaScript SDK V3 .

AWS SDK for Javascript v2 publishes a single npm package that supports all the AWS services. This makes it easy to use multiple services in a project at the cost of a large dependency when only using a handful of services or operations.

In resource constrained environment such as mobile devices, having separate packages for each service client allows optimizing the dependency. The AWS SDK for Javascript v3 provides such modular packages. We have also split up the core parts of the SDK so that service clients only pull in what they need. For example, a service that sends responses in JSON will no longer need to also have an XML parser as a dependency.

As you only import modules that you need, you can do so like below:

`const { S3 } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");`

---

#### SDK V2

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const s3Client = new AWS.S3({});
await s3Client.createBucket(params).promise();
```

#### SDK V3

```
const { S3 } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const s3Client = new S3({});
await s3Client.createBucket(params)
```

#### Backward V2 Compatibility Style

```
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3Client = new AWS.S3({});
await s3Client.createBucket(params);
```

---

#### File Extension

Lambda index.js now has the extension of `.mjs`. Renaming this can sometimes fix any issues you have.

---

[*source*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html)

Comment: Till it resolve the problem of author it's actually has no connection to the head of the question. I have the same error but for "os" module. The error message is generic. But solution is only for "aws-sdk"

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Just change the .mjs extension of index.mjs to index.js

Comment: THIS!!! A typical foolish blunder we all know and love to insist on forgetting...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, "Node18 for Lambda uses JavaScript SDK V3" as [@Lee Hannigan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74887181/1327557)

You can also use a v2 compatible style as describded in [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html#v2-compatible-style) :

```
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when using **ApiGatewayManagementApi**.

I was doing this way in `index.mjs` file.
`const AWS = require('aws-sdk);`

which gave me error:

```html
2023-10-12T10:30:19.291Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
    "stack": [
        "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
        "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"
    ]
}
```

**How I solved the problem?**

I found documentation on how to use ApiGatewayManagementApi in v3. And changed to

`import * as AWS from '@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi';`

and used it like this

```html
import { ApiGatewayManagementApiClient, PostToConnectionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi"; // ES Modules import
// const { ApiGatewayManagementApiClient, PostToConnectionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi"); // CommonJS import

const client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({
  apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
  endpoint: ENDPOINT,
});
const input = { // PostToConnectionRequest
  Data: "BLOB_VALUE", // required
  ConnectionId: "STRING_VALUE", // required
};
const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
// {};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/apigatewaymanagementapi/

Find other modules' details here and change to import statement instead of require accordingly.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should follow the answer by @Leeroy Hannigan, But if you just have to get your version working, I just created a function (with nodejs18) in AWS console , renamed file from index.mjx to index.js and copy pasted the below code, I was able to get past the error you have described(changed exports.handler in your code to module.exports.handler as below).

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
console.log('Hello!');
// some code
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**I found A very very simple solution:**

1. On you AWS Console, select the function in question
2. under the code tab , scroll until you reach runtime Settings
3. select Edit and change to a older version say v12
4. click save
5. attempt to use url again