# Require is not defined in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

First of all, my apologies if this is very trivial but every solution I tried just gave errors.

In short I am new to the aws enviroment and choose a dynamodb to set up as database. I used a lamdba function to be able to batch write data from anywhere to the cloud.

It took some time but I got it all working, however by mistake I chose (or rather used the default) db location us-east-1. Now long story short for legal reasons the data should be in Europe. So I just copied everything, and migrated everything to eu-central-1.

And that's when things when sideways... The code in us-east-1 is running on node.js 16 and uses "const AWS = require("aws-sdk");"

But the same statement in eu-central-1 keeps giving errors. If I run it in node.js 16 it states this:

> errorType": "ReferenceError",
> "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
> "stack": [
> "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
> at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)",
> at async Promise.all (index 0)",
> at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)",
> at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:918:16)",
> at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:967:86)",
> at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:991:16)",
> at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)",
> at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)",
> at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"

And if I run it in node.js 18 (because I found out that the require statement is something added in this version)

> "errorType": "ReferenceError",
> "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
> "stack": [
> "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
> at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"`
> ]

I tried many different syntaxes but none have solved my problem or my knowledge of the problem. When I use the suggested import statement I get errors that the aws-sdk files are not found. But I tried to install them in the same location but that did not work. Probably is this a solution that I should persue but I can't seem to find any clear information on how to succesfully attach the files (I tried to export the Lambda function and attach the aws-sdk in the folder but that gave the same errors) And more Importantly I want to know why this is occurring, because I definetly didn't install aws-sdk in the us-east-1 region and there it works, plus the require statement is defined there.

So any reading, tips, suggestion is welcome. I 'll keep this update and add the code that you need to provide help (or settings or results of proposed changes).

Here is the working Lambda code (from the us-east-1), the code is the same as in eu-central-1 except for the table name and location.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();



exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  
  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "DELETE /items/{id}":
        await dynamo
          .delete({
            TableName: "TestID",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Deleted item ${event.pathParameters.id}`;
        break;
      case "GET /items/{id}":
        body = await dynamo
          .get({
            TableName: "TestID",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        break;
      case "GET /items":
        body = await dynamo.scan({ TableName: "TestID" }).promise();
        break;
      case "PUT /items":
        let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        if (!requestJSON[0].ModuleID || !requestJSON[0].DataID) {
          throw new Error("Missing required fields: ModuleID or DataID, greetings ");
        }
        await dynamo
          .put({
            TableName: "TestID",
            Item: {
              ModuleID: requestJSON[0].ModuleID,
              DataID: requestJSON[0].DataID,
              TimeStamp: requestJSON[0].TimeStamp,
              ValTemp: requestJSON[0].ValTemp
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Put item ${requestJSON[0].DataID}`;
        break;
      case "PUT /items/batch":
        let requestJSONBatch = JSON.parse(event.body);
        let items = requestJSONBatch.map(item => {
          return {
            PutRequest: {
              Item: {
                ModuleID: item.ModuleID,
                DataID: item.DataID,
                TimeStamp: item.TimeStamp,
                T2: item.T2,
                ValTemp: item.ValTemp
              }
            }
          };
        });
        await dynamo
          .batchWrite({
            RequestItems: {
              "TestID": items
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `PUT items`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

I followed the suggestion and changed the first line to:

```
const AWS = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3")
```

And ran the code in node.js 18 ; I get a similar error:

> "errorType": "ReferenceError", "errorMessage": "require is not defined
> in ES module scope, you can use import instead", "stack": [
> "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can
> use import instead", " at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13", " at
> ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)" ]

Comment: Change your Node.js file filename from index.mjs to index.js and ensure you're using Node v16.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I tried that but no solution there. (Exported package, unzipped changed extension and reïmported without losing the error)

Comment: "And if I run it in node.js 18 (because I found out that the require statement is something added in this version)" — Untrue. `require` was added very very very early on in Node.js' history.

Comment: What does your package.json say?

Comment: Yes that is what I keep reading, but I did deploy the code after the change and executed it accordingly. (Just as I do with the code from us-east which works). What do you mean by package.json, should I change the source from @aws-sdk/client-s3 to package.json to see if it is in place?

Comment: if i use import package.json it states: Cannot find package 'package.j' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"
(not sure why the .json is only .j in the error message, I checked my syntax and i wrote .json)

Comment: Make sure you don't have type: module in package.json (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-node-js-es-modules-and-top-level-await-in-aws-lambda/)). You need commonjs.

Comment: "if i use import package.json it states" — Why would you do that? I asked what it said, not that you needed to import it!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't follow your suggestion. could you explain what I should scheck with package.json? Do you mean which syntax I use to send my data via the api to the db?

Comment: I was suggesting you add the contents of your package.json to the question. (But its the module field that I'm most interested in).

Comment: Okay I get what you mean. However I maybe skipped some essential steps here. I only used the web interface and simply clicked my way in creating the lambda and then used the editor from aws in the webbrowser. So I have tried but don't know how to acces the file structure properly. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: I read some things, but still no solution. In my current set up there is no package.json. Should I create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution,

In the end the problem was simple, if you create a lambda function using the webinterface you don't need to add any (regular) dependencies such as the AWS-SDK module, because Amazon takes care of it. However this part stops as soon as you upload a .zip file even if you don't add anything but a code file.

So I downloaded my working code from location x an uploade my code to a different location changed the API and Security accordingly but was unsuccesfull because I had no depencies.

Therefore there was no "package.json" and I didn't understand any of the suggestions and the answer I was able to verify didn't help. In the end, use the aws cli (it takes some reading and understanding to  set up). And add the aws-sdk and upload this using the aws cli.

Details:

AWS-SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js
Instal in a specific directory:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Add .mjs code file to the directory
use 7Zip to zip everything in the directory:

```
 \Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r awslambdav2.zip
```

Update this .zip file as the source for your existing function

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name *insertFunctionName* --zip-file fileb://awslambdav2.zip
```

And you're done! All fixed. In the end the webinterface should not be used to deploy Lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error running the code on Lambda function. It was nodejs v20. I recreated the same function using nodejs v16, ran fine without error.

Answer (score -1):

Node 18 now uses AWS SDK V3 and you should handle your code accordingly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886001/errormessage-require-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope-you-can-use-import-i/74887181#74887181) should help with your imports and enable you to establish a DynamoDB Client in SDK V3.

Use:

```
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
```

Also read [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Comment: Yes I follow your answer. However I'm not implementing it correctly or it doesn't solve all the errors. I added my execution of your solution to the thread.

Comment: Use the V2 compatibility style I shared in my other answer.

Comment: I tried the V2, and the backwards compatible one. If I use your code snippet I get:
Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"
When I used the V2 and option 3 I changed s3Client to dynamo and left out the line with params to work with my code. Am I doing something wrong? If I simply copy paste, the params gives an error in the editor (not declared).