# Lambda function error on importing AWS in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, import, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to import the AWS into the Lambda function, and use that to add a new object to a DynamoDB table. (Nodejs version: 18)

I tried many options to import the AWS:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

```
import AWS from '/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js'
```

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

```
import { DynamoDB } from '@aws-sdk/dynamodb';
```

But neither of them worked out for me, and every time it got me a message similar to this:
"*Cannot find package '<package_name>' imported from* "

(or for the "require" option, I've got "*require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead*")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886001/errormessage-require-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope-you-can-use-import-i

Comment: Be aware that `aws-sdk` is the AWS v2 SDK while `@aws-sdk/dynamodb` is the v3 SDK. Unless you have a specific reason to use v2, you should use v3.

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan thank you but I already tried that.

Comment: @jarmod ok, but neither of them worked out unfortunately.

Comment: Suggest that you start from the beginning if you genuinely want to write a Lambda function in JavaScript. Read the programmer documentation. Both the v2 SDK and the v3 SDK are available and simple to import and use. Note: if you choose the nodejs18.x runtime then you automatically get the AWS JavaScript SDK v3 but if you use nodejs16.x or nodejs14.x runtimes then you get the AWS JavaScript SDK v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`import { DynamoDB } from '@aws-sdk/dynamodb';`

But also rename your `index.js` file to `index.mjs`, that should do the trick.

Comment: My file already has that name. The only solution that I found it was to create a new Lambda function using Python.

Comment: Creating a Node Lambda function with Node 18, with a file named index.mjs and the import statement `import { DynamoDB } from '@aws-sdk/dynamodb';` will definitely work. Double check your configuration, make sure you're not using a layer thats causing conflict.